# How to make an external HTML file not appear in the home page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

cart.php

```
  <div id="main-container">
  <div class="container">
  <span class="top-label">
  <span class="label-txt">Shopping Cart</span>
  </span>

  <div class="content-area">

        <div class="content drop-here">
        <div id="cart-icon">
            <img src="img/Shoppingcart_128x128.png" alt="shopping cart" class="pngfix" width="128" height="128" />
        <img src="img/ajax_load_2.gif" alt="loading.." id="ajax-loader" width="16" height="16" />
            </div>

        <form name="checkoutForm" method="post" action="order.php">

            <div id="item-list"></div>

            </form>                
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="total"></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="" onclick="document.forms.checkoutForm.submit(); return false;" class="button">Checkout</a>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bottom-container-border"></div>
   </div>



  </div>
```

and here is the index.php

```
    include "cart.php";

     ....
     ....
     <div class= "cart"></div> 
     .....
      .....

      <div class="basket"><a href="#" onclick appear cart.php ><span>Shopping Basket</span></a>
      <p><span><?php echo "Amount: ".$ttl ?> </span>Item(s): <strong><?php echo $cnt ?>  </strong></p>
     </div>
```

What I wanna try to do, is to make cart.php appear in

```
  <div class= "cart"></div>
```

as a drop down window, and here is the problem comes, I will have all the cart.php on the top of the index.php when I load index.php even if I set the display property to none in css file.

How can I load the cart.php in div class = cart without being loaded  on the top of the index.php and be appear only on click event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like there's a lot more going on with your markup/styling and how you construct your response with server-side code.  Can you perhaps create a complete and minimal example which replicates the problem, and show the complete server-side and client-side code in that example?

Comment: @David I wanted to find a solution to my issue by myself, but don't know what should I look for? how to load a external php ?  or how to integrate an external php file into the home page? or .... I have tried many different keywords, I could think of, but they lead me no where. I really don't understand why someone down voted the question? I even wrote please don;t down vote, I don't know what's the best title for this question. that was a real smart move. big thumb up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm attaching full code (using your cart.php without changes). You can [test it out on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQDh7/) also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test show()</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Show basket on click
                $('.show_basket').on("click", function(event) {
                    $('.cart').show();
                });

                // Hide basket on click
                $('.hide_basket').on("click", function(event) {
                    $('.cart').hide();
                });

                // Toggle basket - with some extra effects
                $('.toggle_basket').on("click", function(event) {
                    $('.cart').toggle('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="show_basket">SHOW BASKET</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="hide_basket">HIDE BASKET</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="toggle_basket">TOGGLE BASKET</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cart" style="display:none;"><?php include "cart.php"; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Set the CSS of cart to `display:none;` and with jquery (for example) you can try to display it on click. Easiest examples are here: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Good Luck!

Comment: its 1:00 am here, I gonna try your suggested way tomorrow, thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark an answer as correct if it solves your problems.

Comment: i have tried it, and the index page is still showing whole cart.php, still the same issue

Comment: Please check out the full code I provided right now and tell me what is your problem now.

Answer (score 0):

foo.php :

```
<?php
echo 'foo<br>';
?>
```

bar.php :

```
<?php
include 'foo.php';
echo 'bar<br>';
?>
```

Displaying bar.php outputs :

```
foo
bar
```

Check your include order.
Can't say more without a clearer / more detailed explaination and code.